# Navbar does not collapse when zoomed

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and trying to make navbar to collapse when the browser zoomed. The navbar is displaying when zoomed but cannot display the contents !. What went wrong here? 
How to enable navbar to collapse and show its contents?

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="height:70px"> <%--change header div size--%>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" style="background-color:black" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
               <img src="/pic/photoHeader.jpg" height="60" />
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
                    <li id="businessU">
                        <a href="#">Business Units  </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Engineering">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Bioforce">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Biogen">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/AC">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Investor">
                        <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu2">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="contact">
                        <a runat="server" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu3">
                          <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact/Whist">Whistleblowing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="login1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx">Admin Login</asp:LinkButton> </li>
                    <li> <asp:LinkButton ID="Logout" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclick="Logout_Click" style="text-align: right">(logout)</asp:LinkButton></li>

               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *"..trying to make navbar to collapse when the browser zoomed"* -- how are you trying?

Comment: it work with me though you need style a lot because now this look terrible

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have a quick guess: you forgot to include the jquery and bootstrap javascript libraries.

Ensure that these two scripts are included:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the viewport meta tag to your :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)